# Only Generate Data when Dictionary Key is Called

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm trying to make my program a little bit more efficient. I have a certain module that contains large sequences of data. Currently, It's a dictionary of key value pairs that represent the sequence name (key) and multiple generator functions appended together as values. For example:

```
sequences = {
    'One' = make_items(100000) + make_other_items(20)
    'Two' = make_items(9393)
    }
```

Now let's say make_items generates n random strings, n being the integer provided as the argument. As the number of sequences increases, this can severly impact both processing and memory if I only ever need to store the values of one item in the dictionary during program execution. If `sequences` is in the global namespace of the module it will load EVERYTHING when the module is imported and store it in memory the whole time. If I put the dictionary in a function, and return the values I call, the memory issue is solved, but it still will calculate every value of every item in the dictionary when the wrapper function is called - also not that efficient.

My idea was to create a function for each value in the global namespace, and then use a mapper dictionary to actually run the function once an item is called. I'm wondering if this is the cleanest way to do this, as it does add complexity to the code, and having to make sure variables and strings are spelled correctly in multiple locations.

```
sequences = [
    'Sequence One',
    'Sequence Two',
    'Sequence Three',

def SEQUENCE_ONE():
    data = make_items(100000) + make_other_items(20)
    return data

def SEQUENCE_TWO():
    data = make_items(9393)
    return data

def SEQUENCE_THREE():
    data = make_other_items(4)
    return data

def mapper(name):
    map = {
        'Sequence One': SEQUENCE_ONE,
        'Sequence Two': SEQUENCE_TWO,
        'Sequence Three': SEQUENCE_THREE
        }
    data = map[name]()
    return name, data
```

Is this the cleanest, simplest solution, or are there better methods to achieving dynamic generation of data?

Comment: You can not do it that way, since Python evaluates the expression on the right side first. You could however construct some sort of *lazy dictionary* and pass it functions instead of actual values. These fuctions are then calculated when needed.

Comment: It sounds like a good use-case for [cached-property](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cached-property).

Comment: Would [yield/generators](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) help?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for pointing that out - I fixed the code to actually call the function requested in the map. What I have now should work, since the map dict only stores the function reference, and then only said function is evaluated when the data variable is assigned in the mapper function. Unless I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

Proposing for you a more Pythonic alternative by subclassing `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def make_items(n):
    print('making {} items...'.format(n))
    return range(n)

class LazyDict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, k):
        self[k] = make_items(k)
        return self[k]

sequences = LazyDict()
```

It will only generate the values upon first use:

```
>>> sequences = LazyDict()
>>> sequences[10]
making 10 items...
range(0, 10)
>>> sequences[10]
range(0, 10)
```

You can easily adapt the implementation of `__missing__` to raise `KeyError` if the key is not in `{'Sequence One', 'Sequence Two', 'Sequence Three'}`.

Comment: This looks like it almost will work - but I'm not sure how to adapt this to my use case. If you take a look at my sample code, each sequence utilizes different generator functions in different orders specific to that sequence name - so somewhere each sequence name needs to define the exact function calls required for that sequence. Would this be possible to adapt?

Comment: Yes, so you call the functions from inside the `__missing__`.  Try it, I'll leave that part up to you.